Identify this kitchen faucet cartridge?
This faucet is quite old, and I need to replace the cartridge, but I don't know the brand. Also is there an interchangeable cartridge?



That probably is not a cartridge.  It is a faucet stem and has a rubber washer that can be replaced.  To be sure turn off the water and remove it by unscrewing the hex on the shaft.

Is all that black stuff around the kitchen sink mold?  Where is this?

Grohe. Really old, but it's Grohe.
